# Oracle 10g : SQL merging rows into single rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that return below data structure :

```
Course   Math   Science   Computer   Chemistry
------   ----   -------   --------   ---------
CI101     98
CI101     87
CI101             78
CI101             102
CI101                        23
CI101                        56
CI101                        89
CI101                                   45
```

How can have it be in the following structure using SQL:

```
Course   Math   Science   Computer   Chemistry
------   ----   -------   --------   ---------
CI101     98      78        23          45
CI101     87      102       56
CI101                       89
```

Here is SQL I tried:

```
select course,
   case
     when subject = 'MATH' then
      count
   end as MATH,
   case
     when subject = 'SCIENCE' then
      count
   end as SCIENCE,
   case
     when subject = 'COMPUTER' then
      count
   end as COMPUTER,
   case
     when subject = 'CHEMISTRY' then
      count
   end as CHEMISTRY
 from t_course
 GROUP BY course, subject, count
```

Table Structure :

```
Course    Subject     Count
------    -------     -----
CI101     Math         98
....
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I added the table structure in the problem

Comment: In your desired result set, what distinguishes one row from another?  In other words, why isn't there a single CI101 row with totals of Math = 185, Science = 180, Computer = 168, Chemistry = 45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

As I dont have Oracle and I didnt see any answer for this question, I have done this in sql server. This can be easily converted to Oracle sql.

I think, the only part requires conversion is   **ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  [count]) as row_num** which is basically to give a sequence number to each set

```
select CO.course,MA.count as  'MATH',SC.count as 'SCIENCE',CO.count as 'COMPUTER',CH.count as 'CHEMISTRY' from 
(select course,[count],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  [count]) as row_num from t_course where subject = 'MATH')MA full outer join 
(select course,[count],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  [count]) as row_num from t_course where subject = 'SCIENCE')SC on SC.row_num=MA.row_num full outer join 
(select course,[count],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  [count]) as row_num from t_course where subject = 'COMPUTER')CO on CO.row_num=SC.row_num full outer join 
(select course,[count],ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  [count]) as row_num from t_course where subject = 'CHEMISTRY')CH on CO.row_num=CH.row_num
```

Please see the SQL fiddle Demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3640b/1)